# Was my shed repaired properly?

Tags: stucco

There was a leak in our utility shed area about 8' x 6'. The construction of the shed is plywood with stucco covering. The handyman that repaired the rotten wood installed plywood over the rotten wood between the 2x4 inside the shed, and caulked all the seams on the plywood walls and under the roof. Is this an acceptable way to repair the problem? Will the mold and mildew go away, or will the 2x4's continue to rot?

Answer (score 5):

The mold and mildew won't "go away" but if it gets no more moisture, it will die off and not cause any further damage.

However, in my book it is *NEVER* acceptable to just cover up the damage to make it look good.  That's the lazy I don't give a **** way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an acceptable means of repair. You should remove and replace wet, rotted and fungus infected wood. Covering it over is a bad idea. The rot can continue until the wood loses all structural integrity.

It sounds like the repair you got was a schlock job.

Comment: It won't continue to rot *if* the leak was properly sealed.  But we're on the same page otherwise. :)